# Не могу вывести данные из почтового ящика

Tags: python, imap

я учусь работать с почтой,я хотел зайти себе на почту с помощью модуля imaplib и достать из Inbox всех отправителей, по Id письма получается вроде но если хочу пройтись циклом проходит 3 итерации и вылетает ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mihail/Documents/project_python/mailclient/2mail.py", line 24, in <module>
    raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 1280: invalid continuation byte
```

Вот сам код:

```
import imaplib
import email
import email.message




mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.mail.ru')
mail.login('login', 'password')
mail.list()
mail.select('INBOX')
result, data = mail.search(None, "ALL")

ids = data[0]
id_list = ids.split()

print(id_list)

for mail_id in id_list:
    result, data = mail.fetch(mail_id, "RFC822")
    raw_email = data[0][1]
    raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)
    print(email_message['From'])
```

Содержимое raw_email:

**`Delivered-To: vendetta96@list.ru\r\nReturn-path: <info@convertare.ru>\r\nReceived-SPF: pass (mx220.i.mail.ru: domain of convertare.ru designates 134.0.112.92 as permitted sender) client-ip=134.0.112.92; envelope-from=info@convertare.ru; helo=mx1.convertare.ru;\r\nReceived: from vladbulava.ru ([134.0.112.92]:42434 helo=mx1.convertare.ru)\r\n\tby mx220.i.mail.ru with esmtp (envelope-from <info@convertare.ru>)\r\n\tid 1n7xfW-0001KH-Nq\r\n\tfor vendetta96@list.ru; Thu, 13 Jan 2022 13:49:23 +0300\r\nDKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=mx9; d=convertare.ru;\r\n h=From:Date:Subject:Message-id:To:Reply-To:Sender:MIME-Version:Content-Type:\r\n List-Unsubscribe; t=1642070962;\r\n bh=GTFP1AwnupqvC2fdIXp56PfMauuuwZois1ftS4wcQqE=;\r\n b=MCWDB/YWUxXLlPL/N0wgsSso4DP+BDwHpOXRMydGB5Nuts+Zoby6hDCeDuj3l0DcwuJ4Py7Hrk1S\r\n   Y2fhgzZSMoxKxu4DYPvZAdgY02rLsqeKStU1LV/os3S2x2Za1l+2PDIiQPyUidZ6YgyUemQ+EL5K\r\n   AEUHE0ONWsskmr+MOic=\r\nReceived: by mx1.convertare.ru for <vendetta96@list.ru>; Thu, 13 Jan 2022 13:14:39 +0300 (envelope-from <info@convertare.ru>)\r\nFrom: =?utf-8?B?0JzQsNGA0LrQtdGC0LjQvdCzIFBsdXM=?= <info@convertare.ru>\r\nDate: Thu, 13 Jan 2022 02:14:38 -0800\r\nSubject: =?utf-8?B?0YPQstCw0LbQsNC10LzRi9C5KNGPKSB2ZW5kZXR0YSAuLCDQvNGLINC+?=\r\n\t=?utf-8?B?0LHRgNCw0LHQvtGC0LDQu9C4INCy0LDRiCDQv9C+0YHQu9C10LTQvdC4?=\r\n\t=?utf-8?B?0Lkg0LfQsNC60LDQtyAtINC/0L7QttCw0LvRg9C50YHRgtCwINC+0YI=?=\r\n\t=?utf-8?B?0YDQtdCw0LPQuNGA0YPQudGC0LU=?=\r\nMessage-id: <947324.41547.948393.11387@mx9.convertare.ru>\r\nTo: "vendetta ." <vendetta96@list.ru>\r\nReply-To: =?utf-8?B?0JzQsNGA0LrQtdGC0LjQvdCzIFBsdXM=?= <info@convertare.ru>\r\nSender: =?utf-8?B?0JzQsNGA0LrQtdGC0LjQvdCzIFBsdXM=?= <info@convertare.ru>\r\nPrecedence: Bulk\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="ab014892e82c0abe62377ec420e499f55819"\r\nList-Unsubscribe: <http://convertare.ru/e/unsubscribe/?hash=zjvrcpcjllvqzedvzwixxqtiojofzsjtugbyxkldmfdlomutmf?vendetta96@list.ru>\r\nX-Msg-EID: eT4KRxUPuxzuXD1oQQP9JQ2\r\nX-6b629377: 2\r\nX-7564579A: B8F34718100C35BD\r\nX-77F55803: E822A06ED42C499A14E2BB1FC3DCCE2FEDA18F169C816C3CDE9AC03796D867300BBDAAE39103F3638701F0628C4B95CBEC14ED8D1C207DF240078664ED8FE928E4560A4F4C92B58D1856B199EC171585\r\n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r\n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r\nX-C8649E89: 4E36BF7865823D7055A7F0CF078B5EC49A30900B95165D3480665FBD8F49180C6DF8FED4219715E6ACDE1AFFAC6019DE5379E2980246CE2AE3D7CEFE1FE773E51D7E09C32AA3244C54F12E3041FD70ABCC93F9B47FB6EAB2435BF7150578642F3EB3F6AD6EA9203E\r\nX-D57D3AED: 3ZO7eAau8CL7WIMRKs4sN3D3tLDjz0dLbV79QFUyzQ2Ujvy7cMT6pYYqY16iZVKkSc3dCLJ7zSJH7+u4VD18S7Vl4ZUrpaVfd2+vE6kuoey4m4VkSEu530nj6fImhcD4MUrOEAnl0W826KZ9Q+tr59cQFxbtK52nIZkuGRxn/t9t7V/qpiG8u60oWJJ3ph3vI+luKJn93kGzEiMrSMZCAIdQzdHLYu3YbcwOQxq4feHR0F1AaP4EH+I/NBiHtdLfb1+C77++cOEMBjeS2IozJZokQuywxA8I\r\nX-F696D7D5: de7FQ8lhXcThXWqnGL6unfSyAyHHmU+uq8C6DGIZUE+QHV/iRR2avA==\r\nX-Mailru-Dmarc-Auth: dmarc=pass header.from=info@convertare.ru\r\nX-Mras: Ok\r\nX-Spam: undefined\r\nAuthentication-Results: mxs.mail.ru; spf=pass (mx220.i.mail.ru: domain of convertare.ru designates 134.0.112.92 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=info@convertare.ru smtp.helo=mx1.convertare.ru;\r\n\t dkim=pass header.d=convertare.ru; dmarc=pass header.from=info@convertare.ru\r\nX-Mailru-Intl-Transport: d,5c510db\r\n\r\n--ab014892e82c0abe62377ec420e499f55819\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n=D0=A1=D0=B0=D1=80=D0=B0=D1=84=D0=B0=D0=BD=D0=BD=D0=BE=D0=B5 =D1=80=D0=B0=\r\n=D0=B4=D0=B8=D0=BE =E2=80=93 =D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=B8=D0=BD =D0=B8=D0=B7 =D1=81=\r\n=D0=BF=D0=BE=D1=81=D0=BE=D0=B1=D0=BE=D0=B2 =D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=B2=\r\n=D0=B8=D0=B6=D0=B5=D0=BD=D0=B8=D1=8F =D0=B1=D1=80=D0=B5=D0=BD=D0=B4=D0=B0=\r\n. =D0=9A=D0=B0=D0=BA =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=B7=D1=8B=D0=B2=D0=B0=D0=B5=\r\n=D1=82 =D0=B8=D1=81=D1=82=D0=BE=D1=80=D0=B8=D1=8F, =D1=8D=D1=82=D0=BE =D1=\r\n=80=D0=B0=D0=B1=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B0=D0=BB=D0=BE =D0=B2=D1=81=D0=B5=D0=B3=D0=\r\n=B4=D0=B0. =D0=AF=D1=80=D0=BA=D0=B8=D0=B9 =D1=82=D0=BE=D0=BC=D1=83 =D0=BF=\r\n=D1=80=D0=B8=D0=BC=D0=B5=D1=80 =E2=80=93 =D0=B0=D1=80=D0=BC=D1=8F=D0=BD=D1=\r\n=81=D0=BA=D0=B8=D0=B9 =D0=BA=D0=BE=D0=BD=D1=8C=D1=8F=D0=BA. =D0=A1=D0=B5=D0=\r\n=B3=D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=BD=D1=8F =D1=8D=D1=82=D0=BE =D0=B1=D1=80=D0=B5=D0=BD=D0=\r\n=B4, =D0=B8=D0=B7=D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=81=D1=82=D0=BD=D1=8B=D0=B9 =D0=B2=D0=BE =\r\n=D0=B2=D1=81=D0=B5=D0=BC =D0=BC=D0=B8=D1=80=D0=B5. =D0=9E=D0=B4=D0=BD=D0=B0=\r\n=D0=BA=D0=BE =D1=82=D0=B0=D0=BA =D0=B1=D1=8B=D0=BB=D0=BE =D0=BD=D0=B5 =D0=\r\n=B2=D1=81=D0=B5=D0=B3=D0=B4=D0=B0.\r\n\r\n=D0=9A=D0=B0=D0=BA =D1=81=D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=80=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=BE=D1=82=\r\n=D0=B7=D1=8B=D0=B2=D1=8B =D0=BA=D0=BB=D0=B8=D0=B5=D0=BD=D1=82=D0=BE=D0=B2=\r\n?\r\n5 =D1=81=D0=BF=D0=BE=D1=81=D0=BE=D0=B1=D0=BE=D0=B2:\r\n\r\n=D0=9F=D0=BE=D0=B7=D0=B2=D0=BE=D0=BD=D0=B8=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=BF=D0=BE =D1=82=\r\n=D0=B5=D0=BB=D0=B5=D1=84=D0=BE=D0=BD=D1=83. =D0=A7=D1=82=D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=8B=\r\n =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B7=D1=8B=D0=B2 =D0=BD=D0=B5 =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=BB=D1=83=D1=87=\r\n=D0=B8=D0=BB=D1=81=D1=8F =D1=87=D0=B5=D0=BC-=D1=82=D0=BE =D0=B2=D1=80=D0=BE=\r\n=D0=B4=D0=B5 =C2=AB=D0=A1=D0=BF=D0=B0=D1=81=D0=B8=D0=B1=D0=BE, =D1=8F =D0=\r\n=B2=D1=81=D0=B5=D0=BC =D0=B4=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=BE=D0=BB=D0=B5=D0=BD=C2=BB, =D0=\r\n=BD=D1=83=D0=B6=D0=BD=D0=B0 =D0=B3=D1=80=D0=B0=D0=BC=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=BD=D0=\r\n=B0=D1=8F =D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=80=D0=B0=D0=B1=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=BA=D0=B0 =D0=BA=D0=\r\n=BB=D0=B8=D0=B5=D0=BD=D1=82=D0=B0 =D0=BC=D0=B5=D0=BD=D0=B5=D0=B4=D0=B6=D0=\r\n=B5=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=BC. =D0=9F=D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=B3=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=BE=D0=B2=D1=\r\n=8C=D1=82=D0=B5 =D1=81=D1=82=D1=80=D1=83=D0=BA=D1=82=D1=83=D1=80=D1=83 =D0=\r\n=BE=D1=82=D0=B7=D1=8B=D0=B2=D0=B0 =D0=B8 =D1=83=D0=B6=D0=B5 =D0=BF=D0=BE =\r\n=D0=BD=D0=B5=D0=B9 =D0=BE=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=B0=D1=88=D0=B8=D0=B2=D0=B0=D0=B9=\r\n=D1=82=D0=B5 =D0=BA=D0=BB=D0=B8=D0=B5=D0=BD=D1=82=D0=B0.\r\n=D0=95=D1=81=D0=BB=D0=B8 =D0=BD=D0=B5=D1=82 =D0=B2=D0=BE=D0=B7=D0=BC=D0=BE=\r\n=D0=B6=D0=BD=D0=BE=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B8 =D1=80=D0=B0=D0=B1=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B0=\r\n=D1=82=D1=8C =D1=81=D0=BE =D1=81=D1=82=D1=80=D1=83=D0=BA=D1=82=D1=83=D1=80=\r\n=D0=BE=D0=B9, =D1=81=D0=BE=D0=B1=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=B8=D1=82=D0=B5 =D1=81=D0=BF=\r\n=D0=B8=D1=81=D0=BE=D0=BA =D0=BD=D0=B0=D0=B2=D0=BE=D0=B4=D1=8F=D1=89=D0=B8=\r\n=D1=85 =D0=B2=D0=BE=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D1=81=D0=BE=D0=B2.\r\n=D0=96=D0=B5=D0=BB=D0=B0=D1=82=D0=B5=D0=BB=D1=8C=D0=BD=D0=BE =D1=81=D0=BE=\r\n=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B0=D0=B2=D0=B8=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=B2=D0=BE=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=\r\n=D1=81=D1=8B =D1=82=D0=B0=D0=BA=D0=B8=D0=BC=D0=B8, =D1=87=D1=82=D0=BE=D0=B1=\r\n=D1=8B =D0=BD=D0=B0 =D0=BD=D0=B8=D1=85 =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=BB=D1=8C=D0=B7=D0=BE=\r\n=D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=82=D0=B5=D0=BB=D1=8C =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=87=D0=B0=\r\n=D0=BB =D0=BD=D0=B5 =D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D1=81=D1=82=D0=BE =D0=B4=D0=B0/=D0=\r\n=BD=D0=B5=D1=82, =D0=B0 =D1=80=D0=B0=D0=B7=D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=BD=D1=83=D1=\r\n=82=D0=BE.\r\n=D0=A0=D0=B0=D0=B7=D0=B3=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=BE=D1=80 =D0=BC=D0=BE=D0=B6=D0=BD=\r\n=D0=BE =D0=B7=D0=B0=D0=BF=D0=B8=D1=81=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=B8 =D1=80=D0=B0=\r\n=D0=B7=D0=BC=D0=B5=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B8=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=BD=D0=B0 =D1=81=D0=B0=\r\n=D0=B9=D1=82=D0=B5 =D0=B2 =D0=BA=D0=B0=D1=87=D0=B5=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B2=D0=B5=\r\n =D0=B0=D1=83=D0=B4=D0=B8=D0=BE=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B7=D1=8B=D0=B2=D0=B0.\r\n=D0=98=D0=BB=D0=B8 =D0=BC=D0=BE=D0=B6=D0=B5=D1=82=D0=B5 =D0=B7=D0=B0=D1=82=\r\n=D1=80=D0=B0=D0=BD=D1=81=D0=BA=D1=80=D0=B8=D0=B1=D0=B8=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=\r\n=B0=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=B7=D0=B0=D0=BF=D0=B8=D1=81=D1=8C =D0=B8 =D0=B7=D0=B0=D1=\r\n=82=D0=B5=D0=BC =D0=BE=D0=BF=D1=83=D0=B1=D0=BB=D0=B8=D0=BA=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=\r\n=B0=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=B2 =D0=BF=D0=B8=D1=81=D1=8C=D0=BC=D0=B5=D0=BD=D0=BD=D0=\r\n=BE=D0=BC =D0=B2=D0=B8=D0=B4=D0=B5.\r\n\r\n=D0=9D=D0=B0=D0=BF=D0=B8=D1=81=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=BF=D0=B8=D1=81=D1=8C=\r\n=D0=BC=D0=BE =D0=B8=D0=BB=D0=B8 =D1=81=D0=BC=D1=81.\r\n=D0=95=D1=81=D0=BB=D0=B8 =D1=83 =D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=81 =D0=B5=D1=81=D1=82=D1=8C=\r\n =D0=BA=D0=BE=D0=BD=D1=82=D0=B0=D0=BA=D1=82=D0=BD=D1=8B=D0=B5 =D0=B4=D0=B0=\r\n=D0=BD=D0=BD=D1=8B=D0=B5 =D0=BA=D0=BB=D0=B8=D0=B5=D0=BD=D1=82=D0=B0, =D0=BF=\r\n=D0=BE=D1=81=D0=BB=D0=B5 =D0=B7=D0=B0=D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=80=D1=88=D0=B5=D0=BD=\r\n=D0=B8=D1=8F =D0=B7=D0=B0=D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=B7=D0=B0 =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=BF=D1=80=\r\n=D0=B0=D0=B2=D0=BB=D1=8F=D0=B9=D1=82=D0=B5 =D0=B8=D0=BC =D1=81=D0=BE=D0=BE=\r\n=D0=B1=D1=89=D0=B5=D0=BD=D0=B8=D0=B5 =D1=81 =D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D1=81=D1=8C=\r\n=D0=B1=D0=BE=D0=B9 =D0=BE=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B0=D0=B2=D0=B8=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=BE=\r\n=D1=82=D0=B7=D1=8B=D0=B2.\r\n=D0=9D=D0=B5=D1=82 =D0=B3=D0=B0=D1=80=D0=B0=D0=BD=D1=82=D0=B8=D0=B8, =D1=87=\r\n=D1=82=D0=BE =D0=B2=D0=B0=D0=BC =D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=8F=D0=B7=D0=B0=D1=82=D0=B5=\r\n=D0=BB=D1=8C=D0=BD=D0=BE =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=82=D1=8F=D1=82, =D0=BD=\r\n=D0=BE =D1=81=D0=BF=D0=BE=D1=81=D0=BE=D0=B1 =D0=B2 =D0=BF=D1=80=D0=B8=D0=BD=\r\n=D1=86=D0=B8=D0=BF=D0=B5 =D1=80=D0=B0=D0=B1=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B0=D1=8E=D1=89=\r\n=D0=B8=D0=B9.\r\n=D0=98=D0=BC =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=BB=D1=8C=D0=B7=D1=83=D0=B5=D1=82=D1=81=D1=8F=\r\n, =D0=BD=D0=B0=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=B8=D0=BC=D0=B5=D1=80, =D0=BC=D0=BE=D1=8F =D0=\r\n=BB=D1=8E=D0=B1=D0=B8=D0=BC=D0=B0=D1=8F =D0=B4=D0=BE=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B0=D0=\r\n=B2=D0=BA=D0=B0 =D0=BF=D0=B8=D1=86=D1=86=D1=8B:\r\n\r\n=D0=A1=D0=BE=D0=B7=D0=B4=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=8C =D1=81=D0=BE=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B2=\r\n=D0=B5=D1=82=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B2=D1=83=D1=8E=D1=89=D0=B8=D0=B9 =D1=80=D0=B0=\r\n=D0=B7=D0=B4=D0=B5=D0=BB =D0=BD=D0=B0 =D1=81=D0=B0=D0=B9=D1=82=D0=B5.\r\n=D0=95=D1=81=D0=BB=D0=B8 =D0=BD=D0=B0 =D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=88=D0=B5=D0=BC =D1=80=\r\n=D0=B5=D1=81=D1=83=D1=80=D1=81=D0=B5 =D0=B1=D1=83=D0=B4=D0=B5=D1=82 =D0=BE=\r\n=D1=82=D0=B4=D0=B5=D0=BB=D1=8C=D0=BD=D0=B0=D1=8F =D1=81=D1=82=D1=80=D0=B0=\r\n=D0=BD=D0=B8=D1=86=D0=B0 =D0=B4=D0=BB=D1=8F =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B7=D1=8B=D0=B2=\r\n=D0=BE=D0=B2, =D1=82=D0=BE =D0=BD=D0=B0 =D0=BD=D0=B5=D0=B3=D0=BE =D0=B1=D1=\r\n=83=D0=B4=D1=83=D1=82 =D0=B7=D0=B0=D1=85=D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=B8=D1=82=D1=8C =D1=\r\n=87=D0=B0=D1=89=D0=B5 =D0=B8 =D0=BF=D0=B8=D1=81=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=8C =D1=82=D0=\r\n=B0=D0=BC =D1=82=D0=BE=D0=B6=D0=B5.\r\n=D0=9F=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=B5=D0=B6=D0=B8=D0=B2=D0=B0=D0=B5=D1=82=D0=B5, =D1=87=\r\n=D1=82=D0=BE =D1=82=D0=B0=D0=BC =D0=BC=D0=BE=D0=B6=D0=B5=D1=82 =D0=B1=D1=8B=\r\n=D1=82=D1=8C =D1=81=D0=BB=D0=B8=D1=88=D0=BA=D0=BE=D0=BC =D0=BC=D0=BD=D0=BE=\r\n=D0=B3=D0=BE =D0=BD=D0=B5=D0=B3=D0=B0=D1=82=D0=B8=D0=B2=D0=B0? =D0=A1=D0=B4=\r\n=D0=B5=D0=BB=D0=B0=D0=B9=D1=82=D0=B5 =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B7=D1=8B=D0=B2=D1=8B=\r\n =D1=81 =D0=BF=D1=80=D0=B5=D0=BC=D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=B0=D1=86=D0=B8=\r\n=D0=B5=D0=B9.\r\n=D0=A2=D0=B5=D0=BC =D1=81=D0=B0=D0=BC=D1=8B=D0=BC =D0=B2=D1=8B =D0=B4=D0=B0=\r\n=D0=B4=D0=B8=D1=82=D0=B5 =D1=81=D0=B5=D0=B1=D0=B5 =D0=B2=D1=80=D0=B5=D0=BC=\r\n=D1=8F =D1=83=D1=81=D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=BA=D0=BE=D0=B8=D1=82=D1=8C=D1=81=D1=8F=\r\n =D0=B8 =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=B4=D1=83=D0=BC=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=8C, =D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=\r\n=BA =D1=80=D0=B5=D1=88=D0=B8=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=B2=D0=BE=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D1=\r\n=81.\r\n=D0=90 =D0=BF=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=BE=D0=BC =D0=BE=D0=BF=D1=83=D0=B1=D0=BB=D0=B8=\r\n=D0=BA=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=BD=D0=B5=D0=B3=D0=B0=D1=82=D0=B8=\r\n=D0=B2=D0=BD=D1=8B=D0=B9 =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B7=D1=8B=D0=B2 =D0=B8 =D1=81=D1=80=\r\n=D0=B0=D0=B7=D1=83 =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=82 =D0=BD=D0=B0 =D0=BD=D0=B5=\r\n=D0=B3=D0=BE.\r\n\r\n=D0=94=D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=80=D1=8B=D0=B9 =D0=B4=D0=B5=D0=BD=D1=8C.\r\n=D0=92=D1=8B =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=B0=D0=B2=D0=B0=D0=BB=D0=B8 =D0=B7=D0=B0=\r\n=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D1=81 =D0=B2 =D0=BD=D0=B0=D1=88=D1=83 =D1=81=D0=BB=D1=83=\r\n=D0=B6=D0=B1=D1=83 =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=B4=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=B6=D0=BA=D0=B8=\r\n.\r\n\r\n=D0=9C=D1=8B =D1=83=D1=81=D0=BF=D0=B5=D1=88=D0=BD=D0=BE =D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=80=\r\n=D0=B0=D0=B1=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B0=D0=BB=D0=B8 =D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=88 =D0=B7=D0=B0=\r\n=D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=B7.\r\n\r\n=D0=A7=D1=82=D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=8B =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=BB=D1=83=D1=87=D0=B8=D1=82=\r\n=D1=8C =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=B4=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=B1=D0=BD=D0=BE=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B8=\r\n =D0=B2=D0=B0=D0=BC =D0=BD=D1=83=D0=B6=D0=BD=D0=BE =D0=BF=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=B5=\r\n=D0=B9=D1=82=D0=B8 =D0=B2 =D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=B1=D0=B8=D0=BD=D0=B5=D1=82.\r\n\r\n=D0=9F=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=B9=D0=B4=D0=B8=D1=82=D0=B5 =D0=B2 =D0=BD=D0=BE=D0=B2=\r\n=D1=8B=D0=B9 =D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=B1=D0=B8=D0=BD=D0=B5=D1=82\r\n\r\n--ab014892e82c0abe62377ec420e499f55819\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n<html><head>\r\n<meta content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dutf-8" http-equiv=3DContent-Type>\r\n<meta name=3DGENERATOR content=3D"-[OUTLOOK_VER]- 11.00.9600.18052"></hea=\r\nd>\r\n<body>\r\n<div style=3D"DISPLAY: none">\r\n<div><br>=D0=A1=D0=B0=D1=80=D0=B0=D1=84=D0=B0=D0=BD=D0=BD=D0=BE=D0=B5 =D1=\r\n=80=D0=B0=D0=B4=D0=B8=D0=BE =E2=80=93 =D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=B8=D0=BD =D0=B8=D0=B7=\r\n =D1=81=D0=BF=D0=BE=D1=81=D0=BE=D0=B1=D0=BE=D0=B2 =D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=B4=\r\n=D0=B2=D0=B8=D0=B6=D0=B5=D0=BD=D0=B8=D1=8F =D0=B1=D1=80=D0=B5=D0=BD=D0=B4=\r\n=D0=B0. =D0=9A=D0=B0=D0=BA =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=B7=D1=8B=D0=B2=D0=B0=\r\n=D0=B5=D1=82 =D0=B8=D1=81=D1=82=D0=BE=D1=80=D0=B8=D1=8F, =D1=8D=D1=82=D0=BE=\r\n =D1=80=D0=B0=D0=B1=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B0=D0=BB=D0=BE =D0=B2=D1=81=D0=B5=D0=B3=\r\n=D0=B4=D0=B0. =D0=AF=D1=80=D0=BA=D0=B8=D0=B9 =D1=82=D0=BE=D0=BC=D1=83 =D0=\r\n=BF=D1=80=D0=B8=D0=BC=D0=B5=D1=80 =E2=80=93 =D0=B0=D1=80=D0=BC=D1=8F=D0=BD=\r\n=D1=81=D0=BA=D0=B8=D0=B9 =D0=BA=D0=BE=D0=BD=D1=8C=D1=8F=D0=BA. =D0=A1=D0=B5=\r\n=D0=B3=D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=BD=D1=8F =D1=8D=D1=82=D0=BE =D0=B1=D1=80=D0=B5=D0=BD=\r\n=D0=B4, =D0=B8=D0=B7=D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=81=D1=82=D0=BD=D1=8B=D0=B9 =D0=B2=D0=BE=\r\n =D0=B2=D1=81=D0=B5=D0=BC =D0=BC=D0=B8=D1=80=D0=B5. =D0=9E=D0=B4=D0=BD=D0=\r\n=B0=D0=BA=D0=BE =D1=82=D0=B0=D0=BA =D0=B1=D1=8B=D0=BB=D0=BE =D0=BD=D0=B5 =\r\n=D0=B2=D1=81=D0=B5=D0=B3=D0=B4=D0=B0.</div>\r\n<div>&nbsp;</div>\r\n<div>=D0=9A=D0=B0=D0=BA =D1=81=D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=80=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=BE=\r\n=D1=82=D0=B7=D1=8B=D0=B2=D1=8B =D0=BA=D0=BB=D0=B8=D0=B5=D0=BD=D1=82=D0=BE=\r\n=D0=B2? <br>5 =D1=81=D0=BF=D0=BE=D1=81=D0=BE=D0=B1=D0=BE=D0=B2:</div>\r\n<div>&nbsp;</div>\r\n<div>=D0=9F=D0=BE=D0=B7=D0=B2=D0=BE=D0=BD=D0=B8=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=BF=D0=BE =\r\n=D1=82=D0=B5=D0=BB=D0=B5=D1=84=D0=BE=D0=BD=D1=83. =D0=A7=D1=82=D0=BE=D0=B1=\r\n=D1=8B =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B7=D1=8B=D0=B2 =D0=BD=D0=B5 =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=BB=D1=83=\r\n=D1=87=D0=B8=D0=BB=D1=81=D1=8F =D1=87=D0=B5=D0=BC-=D1=82=D0=BE =D0=B2=D1=80=\r\n=D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=B5 =C2=AB=D0=A1=D0=BF=D0=B0=D1=81=D0=B8=D0=B1=D0=BE, =D1=8F=\r\n =D0=B2=D1=81=D0=B5=D0=BC =D0=B4=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=BE=D0=BB=D0=B5=D0=BD=C2=BB=\r\n, =D0=BD=D1=83=D0=B6=D0=BD=D0=B0 =D0=B3=D1=80=D0=B0=D0=BC=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=BD=\r\n=D0=B0=D1=8F =D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=80=D0=B0=D0=B1=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=BA=D0=B0 =D0=BA=\r\n=D0=BB=D0=B8=D0=B5=D0=BD=D1=82=D0=B0 =D0=BC=D0=B5=D0=BD=D0=B5=D0=B4=D0=B6=\r\n=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=BC. =D0=9F=D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=B3=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=BE=D0=B2=\r\n=D1=8C=D1=82=D0=B5 =D1=81=D1=82=D1=80=D1=83=D0=BA=D1=82=D1=83=D1=80=D1=83=\r\n =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B7=D1=8B=D0=B2=D0=B0 =D0=B8 =D1=83=D0=B6=D0=B5 =D0=BF=D0=\r\n=BE =D0=BD=D0=B5=D0=B9 =D0=BE=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=B0=D1=88=D0=B8=D0=B2=D0=B0=D0=\r\n=B9=D1=82=D0=B5 =D0=BA=D0=BB=D0=B8=D0=B5=D0=BD=D1=82=D0=B0. <br>=D0=95=D1=\r\n=81=D0=BB=D0=B8 =D0=BD=D0=B5=D1=82 =D0=B2=D0=BE=D0=B7=D0=BC=D0=BE=D0=B6=D0=\r\n=BD=D0=BE=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B8 =D1=80=D0=B0=D0=B1=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=\r\n=8C =D1=81=D0=BE =D1=81=D1=82=D1=80=D1=83=D0=BA=D1=82=D1=83=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=\r\n=B9, =D1=81=D0=BE=D0=B1=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=B8=D1=82=D0=B5 =D1=81=D0=BF=D0=B8=D1=\r\n=81=D0=BE=D0=BA =D0=BD=D0=B0=D0=B2=D0=BE=D0=B4=D1=8F=D1=89=D0=B8=D1=85 =D0=\r\n=B2=D0=BE=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D1=81=D0=BE=D0=B2. <br>=D0=96=D0=B5=D0=BB=D0=B0=\r\n=D1=82=D0=B5=D0=BB=D1=8C=D0=BD=D0=BE =D1=81=D0=BE=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B0=D0=B2=\r\n=D0=B8=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=B2=D0=BE=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D1=81=D1=8B =D1=82=D0=B0=\r\n=D0=BA=D0=B8=D0=BC=D0=B8, =D1=87=D1=82=D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=8B =D0=BD=D0=B0 =D0=\r\n=BD=D0=B8=D1=85 =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=BB=D1=8C=D0=B7=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=82=D0=\r\n=B5=D0=BB=D1=8C =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=87=D0=B0=D0=BB =D0=BD=D0=B5 =D0=\r\n=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D1=81=D1=82=D0=BE =D0=B4=D0=B0/=D0=BD=D0=B5=D1=82, =D0=B0=\r\n =D1=80=D0=B0=D0=B7=D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=BD=D1=83=D1=82=D0=BE. <br>=D0=A0=\r\n=D0=B0=D0=B7=D0=B3=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=BE=D1=80 =D0=BC=D0=BE=D0=B6=D0=BD=D0=BE=\r\n =D0=B7=D0=B0=D0=BF=D0=B8=D1=81=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=B8 =D1=80=D0=B0=D0=B7=\r\n=D0=BC=D0=B5=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B8=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=BD=D0=B0 =D1=81=D0=B0=D0=B9=\r\n=D1=82=D0=B5 =D0=B2 =D0=BA=D0=B0=D1=87=D0=B5=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B2=D0=B5 =D0=B0=\r\n=D1=83=D0=B4=D0=B8=D0=BE=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B7=D1=8B=D0=B2=D0=B0. <br>=D0=98=D0=\r\n=BB=D0=B8 =D0=BC=D0=BE=D0=B6=D0=B5=D1=82=D0=B5 =D0=B7=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=80=D0=\r\n=B0=D0=BD=D1=81=D0=BA=D1=80=D0=B8=D0=B1=D0=B8=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=82=\r\n=D1=8C =D0=B7=D0=B0=D0=BF=D0=B8=D1=81=D1=8C =D0=B8 =D0=B7=D0=B0=D1=82=D0=B5=\r\n=D0=BC =D0=BE=D0=BF=D1=83=D0=B1=D0=BB=D0=B8=D0=BA=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=82=\r\n=D1=8C =D0=B2 =D0=BF=D0=B8=D1=81=D1=8C=D0=BC=D0=B5=D0=BD=D0=BD=D0=BE=D0=BC=\r\n =D0=B2=D0=B8=D0=B4=D0=B5.</div>\r\n<div>&nbsp;</div>\r\n<div>=D0=9D=D0=B0=D0=BF=D0=B8=D1=81=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=BF=D0=B8=D1=81=D1=\r\n=8C=D0=BC=D0=BE =D0=B8=D0=BB=D0=B8 =D1=81=D0=BC=D1=81. <br>=D0=95=D1=81=D0=\r\n=BB=D0=B8 =D1=83 =D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=81 =D0=B5=D1=81=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=BA=D0=BE=\r\n=D0=BD=D1=82=D0=B0=D0=BA=D1=82=D0=BD=D1=8B=D0=B5 =D0=B4=D0=B0=D0=BD=D0=BD=\r\n=D1=8B=D0=B5 =D0=BA=D0=BB=D0=B8=D0=B5=D0=BD=D1=82=D0=B0, =D0=BF=D0=BE=D1=81=\r\n=D0=BB=D0=B5 =D0=B7=D0=B0=D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=80=D1=88=D0=B5=D0=BD=D0=B8=D1=8F=\r\n =D0=B7=D0=B0=D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=B7=D0=B0 =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=B0=D0=B2=\r\n=D0=BB=D1=8F=D0=B9=D1=82=D0=B5 =D0=B8=D0=BC =D1=81=D0=BE=D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=89=\r\n=D0=B5=D0=BD=D0=B8=D0=B5 =D1=81 =D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D1=81=D1=8C=D0=B1=D0=BE=\r\n=D0=B9 =D0=BE=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B0=D0=B2=D0=B8=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B7=\r\n=D1=8B=D0=B2. <br>=D0=9D=D0=B5=D1=82 =D0=B3=D0=B0=D1=80=D0=B0=D0=BD=D1=82=\r\n=D0=B8=D0=B8, =D1=87=D1=82=D0=BE =D0=B2=D0=B0=D0=BC =D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=8F=D0=\r\n=B7=D0=B0=D1=82=D0=B5=D0=BB=D1=8C=D0=BD=D0=BE =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=\r\n=82=D1=8F=D1=82, =D0=BD=D0=BE =D1=81=D0=BF=D0=BE=D1=81=D0=BE=D0=B1 =D0=B2=\r\n =D0=BF=D1=80=D0=B8=D0=BD=D1=86=D0=B8=D0=BF=D0=B5 =D1=80=D0=B0=D0=B1=D0=BE=\r\n=D1=82=D0=B0=D1=8E=D1=89=D0=B8=D0=B9.<br>=D0=98=D0=BC =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=BB=D1=\r\n=8C=D0=B7=D1=83=D0=B5=D1=82=D1=81=D1=8F, =D0=BD=D0=B0=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=B8=D0=\r\n=BC=D0=B5=D1=80, =D0=BC=D0=BE=D1=8F =D0=BB=D1=8E=D0=B1=D0=B8=D0=BC=D0=B0=D1=\r\n=8F =D0=B4=D0=BE=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B0=D0=B2=D0=BA=D0=B0 =D0=BF=D0=B8=D1=86=D1=\r\n=86=D1=8B:</div>\r\n<div>&nbsp;</div>\r\n<div><br>=D0=A1=D0=BE=D0=B7=D0=B4=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=8C =D1=81=D0=BE=D0=BE=D1=\r\n=82=D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=82=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B2=D1=83=D1=8E=D1=89=D0=B8=D0=B9 =D1=\r\n=80=D0=B0=D0=B7=D0=B4=D0=B5=D0=BB =D0=BD=D0=B0 =D1=81=D0=B0=D0=B9=D1=82=D0=\r\n=B5. <br>=D0=95=D1=81=D0=BB=D0=B8 =D0=BD=D0=B0 =D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=88=D0=B5=D0=\r\n=BC =D1=80=D0=B5=D1=81=D1=83=D1=80=D1=81=D0=B5 =D0=B1=D1=83=D0=B4=D0=B5=D1=\r\n=82 =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B4=D0=B5=D0=BB=D1=8C=D0=BD=D0=B0=D1=8F =D1=81=D1=82=D1=\r\n=80=D0=B0=D0=BD=D0=B8=D1=86=D0=B0 =D0=B4=D0=BB=D1=8F =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B7=D1=\r\n=8B=D0=B2=D0=BE=D0=B2, =D1=82=D0=BE =D0=BD=D0=B0 =D0=BD=D0=B5=D0=B3=D0=BE=\r\n =D0=B1=D1=83=D0=B4=D1=83=D1=82 =D0=B7=D0=B0=D1=85=D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=B8=D1=82=\r\n=D1=8C =D1=87=D0=B0=D1=89=D0=B5 =D0=B8 =D0=BF=D0=B8=D1=81=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=8C=\r\n =D1=82=D0=B0=D0=BC =D1=82=D0=BE=D0=B6=D0=B5. <br>=D0=9F=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=B5=\r\n=D0=B6=D0=B8=D0=B2=D0=B0=D0=B5=D1=82=D0=B5, =D1=87=D1=82=D0=BE =D1=82=D0=B0=\r\n=D0=BC =D0=BC=D0=BE=D0=B6=D0=B5=D1=82 =D0=B1=D1=8B=D1=82=D1=8C =D1=81=D0=BB=\r\n=D0=B8=D1=88=D0=BA=D0=BE=D0=BC =D0=BC=D0=BD=D0=BE=D0=B3=D0=BE =D0=BD=D0=B5=\r\n=D0=B3=D0=B0=D1=82=D0=B8=D0=B2=D0=B0? =D0=A1=D0=B4=D0=B5=D0=BB=D0=B0=D0=B9=\r\n=D1=82=D0=B5 =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B7=D1=8B=D0=B2=D1=8B =D1=81 =D0=BF=D1=80=D0=B5=\r\n=D0=BC=D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=B0=D1=86=D0=B8=D0=B5=D0=B9. <br>=D0=A2=D0=\r\n=B5=D0=BC =D1=81=D0=B0=D0=BC=D1=8B=D0=BC =D0=B2=D1=8B =D0=B4=D0=B0=D0=B4=D0=\r\n=B8=D1=82=D0=B5 =D1=81=D0=B5=D0=B1=D0=B5 =D0=B2=D1=80=D0=B5=D0=BC=D1=8F =D1=\r\n=83=D1=81=D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=BA=D0=BE=D0=B8=D1=82=D1=8C=D1=81=D1=8F =D0=B8 =D0=\r\n=BF=D0=BE=D0=B4=D1=83=D0=BC=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=8C, =D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=BA =D1=80=D0=\r\n=B5=D1=88=D0=B8=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=B2=D0=BE=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D1=81. <br>=D0=\r\n=90 =D0=BF=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=BE=D0=BC =D0=BE=D0=BF=D1=83=D0=B1=D0=BB=D0=B8=D0=\r\n=BA=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=BD=D0=B5=D0=B3=D0=B0=D1=82=D0=B8=D0=\r\n=B2=D0=BD=D1=8B=D0=B9 =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B7=D1=8B=D0=B2 =D0=B8 =D1=81=D1=80=D0=\r\n=B0=D0=B7=D1=83 =D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B2=D0=B5=D1=82 =D0=BD=D0=B0 =D0=BD=D0=B5=D0=\r\n=B3=D0=BE.</div></div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div>\r\n<div align=3Dcenter>=D0=94=D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=80=D1=8B=D0=B9 =D0=B4=D0=B5=D0=BD=\r\n=D1=8C.<br>&nbsp;<br>=D0=92=D1=8B =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=B0=D0=B2=D0=B0=D0=\r\n=BB=D0=B8 =D0=B7=D0=B0=D0=BF=D1=80=D0=BE=D1=81 =D0=B2 =D0=BD=D0=B0=D1=88=D1=\r\n=83 =D1=81=D0=BB=D1=83=D0=B6=D0=B1=D1=83 =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=B4=D0=B4=D0=B5=D1=\r\n=80=D0=B6=D0=BA=D0=B8.</div>\r\n<div align=3Dcenter>&nbsp;</div>\r\n<div align=3Dcenter>=D0=9C=D1=8B =D1=83=D1=81=D0=BF=D0=B5=D1=88=D0=BD=D0=BE=\r\n =D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=80=D0=B0=D0=B1=D0=BE=D1=82=D0=B0=D0=BB=D0=B8 =D0=B2=D0=B0=\r\n=D1=88 =D0=B7=D0=B0=D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=B7.</div>\r\n<div align=3Dcenter>&nbsp;</div>\r\n<div align=3Dcenter>=D0=A7=D1=82=D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=8B =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=BB=D1=83=\r\n=D1=87=D0=B8=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=B4=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=B1=D0=BD=D0=BE=\r\n=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B8 =D0=B2=D0=B0=D0=BC =D0=BD=D1=83=D0=B6=D0=BD=D0=BE =D0=BF=\r\n=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=B5=D0=B9=D1=82=D0=B8 =D0=B2 =D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=B1=D0=B8=D0=BD=\r\n=D0=B5=D1=82.</div>\r\n<div align=3Dcenter>&nbsp;</div>\r\n<div align=3Dcenter><strong><a href=3D"http://convertare.ru/contact/?cont=\r\nact=3Dvendetta96@list.ru">=D0=9F=D1=80=D0=BE=D0=B9=D0=B4=D0=B8=D1=82=D0=B5=\r\n =D0=B2 =D0=BD=D0=BE=D0=B2=D1=8B=D0=B9 =D0=BA=D0=B0=D0=B1=D0=B8=D0=BD=D0=B5=\r\n=D1=82</a></strong></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>=\r\n</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><=\r\n/div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></=\r\ndiv></div></div></div></div></body></html>\r\n\r\n--ab014892e82c0abe62377ec420e499f55819--\r\n'`**

Comment: Я нуб не ругайте

Comment: никто не будет=) вопрос: что содежится в `raw_email`? Добавьте в сам вопрос кусочек. мне почему то кажется, что у вас там base64 кодированное сообщение.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: не, мои предположения не верны=(

Answer (score 0):

Но нашел в чем может быть проблема. Если вы используете метод `decode()`, следовательно тип данных для `raw_email` может быть `bytes`.

Воссоздадим вашу ошибку

```py
>>> value_for_fail = b'\xc7'
>>> value_for_fail.decode("utf-8") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

Мой вывод, что у вас не верна кодировка. `utf-8` сюда не подходит. Попробуем другую

```py
>>> value_for_fail.decode("cp1251") 
'З'
```

все работает.

Разбирайтесь с кодировками при чтении почты.

Comment: Спасибо попробую

Answer (score 0):

```
for mail_id in id_list:
    _, data = mail.fetch(mail_id,'(RFC822)')
    _, bytes_data = data[0]
    email_message = email.message_from_bytes(bytes_data)
    print(email_message["from"])
```

Вот так решил вопрос,нашел на каком то англоязычном сайте пример с

```
email.message_from_bytes(bytes_data)
```